# Java Keyboard Keycodes list

Tags: java, applet, keylistener, keyevent

Can anybody provide me with the Key Code integer list for individual keys used on the Keyboard for the KeyEvent class in java?

I want to create a dropdown list of all the keyboard keys for the user to select. I need the list specific to Keyboard. The VK constants does not help in this case because I need a 'list' of Keys used on the Keyboard.
 [This post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627925/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-keyboard-keycodes) didn't come of use because it's for Javascript and the codes aren't the same for all keys comparing with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M). Also the KeyCode values used in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M) are all arranged in Alphabetical Order, so it's hard to find the Keyboard keys over there. I tried googling for sources but nothing interesting came up just the Javascript one. Should I just compile them one by one myself or is there an easier way?

Edit: I know about VK. I need to use KeyEvent.getKeyText function to store each of the keyboard keys in a dropdown menu. So i need the list. That's why I asked should I need to compile them myself. I should have mentioned that earlier. It would be a waste of time doing that for each key.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class has static fields with these values.

For example, `KeyEvent.VK_A` represent "A" key.

To get the fields names you can use reflection:

```
Field[] fields = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
    if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer. This will give the fields names. Then you'll need to "edit" the strings to put in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @AbdudDayanAdeeb, if this solved your problem then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 47):

This is your list:

```
3 -- Cancel
8 -- Backspace
9 -- Tab
10 -- Enter
12 -- Clear
16 -- Shift
17 -- Ctrl
18 -- Alt
19 -- Pause
20 -- Caps Lock
21 -- Kana
24 -- Final
25 -- Kanji
27 -- Escape
28 -- Convert
29 -- No Convert
30 -- Accept
31 -- Mode Change
32 -- Space
33 -- Page Up
34 -- Page Down
35 -- End
36 -- Home
37 -- Left
38 -- Up
39 -- Right
40 -- Down
44 -- Comma
45 -- Minus
46 -- Period
47 -- Slash
48 -- 0
49 -- 1
50 -- 2
51 -- 3
52 -- 4
53 -- 5
54 -- 6
55 -- 7
56 -- 8
57 -- 9
59 -- Semicolon
61 -- Equals
65 -- A
66 -- B
67 -- C
68 -- D
69 -- E
70 -- F
71 -- G
72 -- H
73 -- I
74 -- J
75 -- K
76 -- L
77 -- M
78 -- N
79 -- O
80 -- P
81 -- Q
82 -- R
83 -- S
84 -- T
85 -- U
86 -- V
87 -- W
88 -- X
89 -- Y
90 -- Z
91 -- Open Bracket
92 -- Back Slash
93 -- Close Bracket
96 -- NumPad-0
97 -- NumPad-1
98 -- NumPad-2
99 -- NumPad-3
100 -- NumPad-4
101 -- NumPad-5
102 -- NumPad-6
103 -- NumPad-7
104 -- NumPad-8
105 -- NumPad-9
106 -- NumPad *
107 -- NumPad +
108 -- NumPad ,
109 -- NumPad -
110 -- NumPad .
111 -- NumPad /
112 -- F1
113 -- F2
114 -- F3
115 -- F4
116 -- F5
117 -- F6
118 -- F7
119 -- F8
120 -- F9
121 -- F10
122 -- F11
123 -- F12
127 -- Delete
128 -- Dead Grave
129 -- Dead Acute
130 -- Dead Circumflex
131 -- Dead Tilde
132 -- Dead Macron
133 -- Dead Breve
134 -- Dead Above Dot
135 -- Dead Diaeresis
136 -- Dead Above Ring
137 -- Dead Double Acute
138 -- Dead Caron
139 -- Dead Cedilla
140 -- Dead Ogonek
141 -- Dead Iota
142 -- Dead Voiced Sound
143 -- Dead Semivoiced Sound
144 -- Num Lock
145 -- Scroll Lock
150 -- Ampersand
151 -- Asterisk
152 -- Double Quote
153 -- Less
154 -- Print Screen
155 -- Insert
156 -- Help
157 -- Meta
160 -- Greater
161 -- Left Brace
162 -- Right Brace
192 -- Back Quote
222 -- Quote
224 -- Up
225 -- Down
226 -- Left
227 -- Right
240 -- Alphanumeric
241 -- Katakana
242 -- Hiragana
243 -- Full-Width
244 -- Half-Width
245 -- Roman Characters
256 -- All Candidates
257 -- Previous Candidate
258 -- Code Input
259 -- Japanese Katakana
260 -- Japanese Hiragana
261 -- Japanese Roman
262 -- Kana Lock
263 -- Input Method On/Off
512 -- At
513 -- Colon
514 -- Circumflex
515 -- Dollar
516 -- Euro
517 -- Exclamation Mark
518 -- Inverted Exclamation Mark
519 -- Left Parenthesis
520 -- Number Sign
521 -- Plus
522 -- Right Parenthesis
523 -- Underscore
524 -- Windows
525 -- Context Menu
61440 -- F13
61441 -- F14
61442 -- F15
61443 -- F16
61444 -- F17
61445 -- F18
61446 -- F19
61447 -- F20
61448 -- F21
61449 -- F22
61450 -- F23
61451 -- F24
65312 -- Compose
65368 -- Begin
65406 -- Alt Graph
65480 -- Stop
65481 -- Again
65482 -- Props
65483 -- Undo
65485 -- Copy
65487 -- Paste
65488 -- Find
65489 -- Cut
```

I generated it with this plain bruteforce:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;                                                               
import java.lang.reflect.Field;                                                               
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;                                                            
import java.util.*;                                                                           
                                                                                              
public class Test {                                                                           
    public static void main(String[] a) {                                                     
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {                                                    
            String text = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.getKeyText(i);                              
            if(!text.contains("Unknown keyCode: ")) {                                         
                System.out.println("" + i + " -- " + text);                                   
            }                                                                                 
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
    }                                                                                         
}
```

I have excluded the "unknown" codes.

Comment: I know it is old topic, but somebody may find this helpful

Comment: Thanks for this! Just curious where you pulled this from?

Comment: Just bruteforced all the keys to some reasonable number. Tbh this was just a random answer that I posted when I started to learn actual programming and it is still the most rated one out of all my posts

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to know the exact value of key codes. `KeyEvent` class has constants fields defining all the key codes:

```
KeyEvent.VK_A
KeyEvent.VK_ENTER
KeyEvent.VK_SPACE
```

etc.

Please read Javadoc carefully. All the constant values can also be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html

Comment: It doesn't help. I know about VK. My question was about compiling the list of KeyCodes rather than using each KeyCode. That's why I asked if i should compile them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this program to get all the int values of the fields in the `KeyEvent` class

```
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.*;
public class RobotClass 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {   
      ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
      try{
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         Field[] fields = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields();
         for (Field f : fields) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
               values.add(f.getInt(f.getName()));
           } 
         }         
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         Collections.sort(values);
         for(int i:values) System.out.println(i);
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Java™ Platform
Standard Ed. 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED)

look for "java.awt.event.KeyEvent" section there;

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as the accepted answer except that now you are linking to an unsupported version of Java.