# Is there a way to get "Del" as shortcut instead of "Delete" for a JMenuItem

Tags: java, shortcut, jmenuitem

When I use this code, I get "Delete" as a shortcut. I want to get "Del" (delete key)

`private JMenuItem delRef = null;`

`del = new JMenuItem("delete");`

`del.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0));`

Answer (score 0):

From [an answer in a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637206), I found out that the `keyCode` (first parameter of `getKeyStroke`) which you are requesting is `110`.

Then I did:

```
System.out.println(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(110, 0));
```

Which prints `pressed DECIMAL`.

So the `keyCode` you are looking for is actually `KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL` and it will only work (at least as far as I tested it) for the numpad's delete key (only when numlock is on).

So to answer, you can use:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Delete");
item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL, 0));
item.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Action delete!"));
```