# AssertJ Swing enterText() writing wrong symbols

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jspinner, assertj

I'm using Swing to create a GUI for my application that has a `JSpinner` named "spinner". Inside the tests, created using AssertJ Swing I have something like this:

```
import org.assertj.swing.fixture.FrameFixture;
import org.assertj.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner;

FrameFixture window;
MyView view;
GuiActionRunner.execute(() -> {
    view = new MyView();
    return view;
});
window = new FrameFixture(view);
window.spinner("spinner").enterText("-1");
```

This code runs without any problems on Ubuntu. However while testing the same code on MacOS with an Italian keyboard, I've noticed that instead of entering "-1" the text written is "'1". This happens also for other symbols like "\\" that turns into an "ù".

If I manually enter "-1" inside the spinner on mac it is written ok. So I guess the problem is associated to `enterText()` itself and mac.
Does anyone has an idea of why this is happening? Thanks.

**Update:**

In order to isolate the problem I've also tried doing:

```
String minus = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.getKeyText(45);
System.out.println(minus);
```

From this [cheat sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637206/14774959), I know that `45` key corresponds to `-` and indeed this code works correctly.

But then I've tried:

```
window.spinner("spinner").click();
window.robot().pressAndReleaseKeys(45);
```

Or similarly by creating a new robot:

```
robot = new Robot();
robot.setAutoDelay(500); 
window.spinner("spinner").click();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
```

This two fragment of code again instead of writing `-` write `'`. From [this](https://groups.google.com/g/easytesting/c/UatnlgVOPeU/m/KOLJ2r56ucoJ) old discussion I suspect that there is a bug in the key mapping for the Italian keyboard in a way similar to the bugs mentioned in the discussion for the French and German keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-swing/issues/199#issuecomment-302068893), I've discovered that the tests can be executed using the following VM argument for assertj:

```
-Dassertj.swing.keyboard.locale=language
```

Indeed by specifying a different language the keyboard mapping changes, overriding the default one.
Of course choosing "it" as language hasn't solved the problem. I did some tests changing different keyboard locale. The one that works the best for my italian MacBook is surprisingly the Finnish keyboard layout.

I've tested a few symbols with:

```java
window.spinner("spinner").enterText("-123456789;.,_èé@)(/&%$£|\"!<>ìàòùabcdefghilmnopqrstuvzwxyjk");
```

The resulting text is:

```
-123456789;.,?èé2)(/&%43"!lìàòùabcdefghilmnopqrstuvzwxyjk
```

Some character are still not correctly mapped, but is way better than before. For the tests that I have in my GUI this is enough. Still I would appreciate a more entirely correct solution.

In the assertj documentation I've found the [KeyStrokeMappingProvider](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/swing/api/org/assertj/swing/keystroke/class-use/KeyStrokeMappingProvider.html) class that can be used for mapping. Besides the default one there are currently available keystroke mapping providers for German, English, Finnish, French and French + macOS. My guess is that there should be also a mapping provider for the Italian + macOS layout.